# Can I combine rules with a URL rewrite in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web, webserver

My rules look like this:

```
    <rule name="SpecificRedirect1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^home" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="SpecificRedirect2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^admin" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

I want to add more also pointing to url="/"

Is there a way I can combine the matching to just one line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this answer doesn't exactly match your question, I'm suspecting you did not take into account urls that start with something like `homely` that will match the rules

Update: Like @Smirnov says below a the pattern could be simplified to `^((home|admin)(/|$))`

Hence this Regex should work: `^(((home|admin)/)|((home|admin)$))`

It will match paths that are exactly home or admin and have no trailing slash or paths that start with home or admin and have trailing slashes.

You can easily test the rules in: http://regexhero.net/tester (not mine nor am I affiliated with it :). Check the multiline option to test multiple paths.

[image] [image: Screenshot 2 from regexhero]

So finally the rule should look like:

```
<match url="^((home|admin)(/|$))" />
```

Comment: Same pattern could be written as "^(home|admin)(/|$)" but OP didn't mention that "homefd" or "adminfd" should be not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pipe as an "OR" operator, like so:

```
<match url="^home|admin" />
```

This would match on both mydomain.com/home and mydomain.com/admin.

EDIT

If you want anything starting with home or admin, try this:

```
<match url="^(admin|home)(.*)" />
```

This will match /admin/help/whatever.htm or /admin123abc or pretty much anything else that starts with admin or home.

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not seem to work. I want anything starting with home or anything starting with admin. I also tried "^[home|admin] but that does not work either.

Comment: For me "^home|admin" works as expected. You can also try to use "^home|admin$" because your current rule will match /home2 or /administrator. You can also try "^(get|admin)"